# React JS routing nothing is displaying

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Im new at routing on react.JS, however I have been struggling because the simple products.jsx
should return a simple message when I click, but no one is displaying.

Index.JS code

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
<BrowserRouter>
    <App />
</BrowserRouter>
, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

code at App.JS

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import NavBar from "./components/navbar";
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Products from "./components/products";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <NavBar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path= "/products" component={Products}></Route>
        </Routes>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

nav.jsx

```
import React from "react";

const NavBar = () => {
  return (
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/products">Products</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/posts/2018/06">Posts</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/admin">Admin</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  );
};

export default NavBar;
```

products.jsx code

```
const Product = () => {
  return <h1>Products</h1>;
};

export default Product;
```

I dont know basically what i'm missing.

Comment: Hi, Just change ` <Route path="products" element={<Products/>} />` and you are good to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `react-router-dom` v6 the `Route` components render their components on the `element` prop ***as JSX***.

```
<Route path="/products" element={<Products />} />
```

If you are still using v5 and have just mixed up documentation, then in v5 use the `Switch` instead (*`Routes` replaced `Switch` in v6*) and use the `component` prop as you were.

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/products" component={Products} />
</Switch>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using react-router-dom 6, you have to use element instead of component inside  of each route like this:

```
        <Routes>
          <Route path= "/products" element={<Products/>}></Route>
        </Routes>
```

if you are using react-router-dom 5, you have to use Switch instead of Routes, like this:

```
        <Switch>
          <Route path= "/products" component={Products}></Route>
        </Switch>
```